# Efficient way to join by levenshtein in Hive or Impala

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, impala, levenshtein-distance

I have two tables one includes about 17K (`NLIST`) records while the other 57K (`FNAMES`).

I would like to join the both by comparing the records using levenshtein formula.

Here is the example for the content of tables:

Table `NLIST`:

```
+------+-------------+
| ID   |   S_NAME    |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |   Avi       |
|  2   |   Moshe     |
|  3   |   David     |
....
```

Table `FNAMES`:

```
+------+-------------+
| ID   |   NICKNAMES |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |  Avile      |
|  2   |  Dudi       |
|  3   |  Moshiko    |
|  4   |  Avi        |
|  5   |  DAVE       |
....
```

The above tables are just examples. In the real case the names column can include more than one word.

The required result should be:

```
+------+-------------+--------+
| ID   |   NICKNAMES | S_NAME |
+------+-------------+--------+
|  1   |  Avile      | Avi    |
|  2   |  Dudi       | David  |
|  3   |  Moshiko    | Moshe  |
|  4   |  Avi        | Avi    |
|  5   |  DAVE       | David  |
...
```

Here is the code I use:

```
select FNAMES.NICKNAMES, NLIST.S_NAME  
from NICKNAMES
LEFT OUTER JOIN NLIST
ON(true)  
WHERE levenshtein (FNAMES.NICKNAMES, NLIST.S_NAME) <=4
```

The above code runs for a very long time and I stopped its running.

How can I make it run in a reasonable time?

In addition, I think the `levenshtein` distance depends on the length of the words. How can I find the optimal value for the distance (in this case I chose 4 arbitrarily)?

Comment: Avi, for start, have you took **distinct values** from both tables?

Comment: Thanks Dudu, Sure yes I did. The NLIST table is already a distinct table and FNAMES tables does not have duplicate values.

Answer (score -2):

`Hive` Table performance is depends upon various point .

- Query enginee
- File format
- use VECTORIZATION `set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;`

If you have good server you can try with `Impala` and definitely it is faster than `Hive`.

You can do the fine tuning of `impala` which will give you an edge to execute this query faster .[Tuning Impala for Performance](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/impala_performance.html)